# Serving files from GridFS with casbah/salat

Tags: mongodb, scala, gridfs, casbah

I would like to store images uploaded as user content in `GridFS` in a Scala Play 2 application. How can I restore the binary file from the `GridFSDBFile` that `GridFS.findOne` gives me?

Answer (score 0):

You could serve the file by streaming its contents and setting the correct http headers - an example of doing so is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135653/any-sample-to-store-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-gridfs-scala-and-playfr).

```
def getPhoto(file: ObjectId) = Action {
  import com.mongodb.casbah.Implicits._

  val gridFs = salat.gridFS("photos")

  gridFs.findOne(Map("_id" -> file)) match {
    case Some(f) => SimpleResult(
      ResponseHeader(OK, Map(
        CONTENT_LENGTH -> f.length.toString,
        CONTENT_TYPE -> f.contentType.getOrElse(BINARY),
        DATE -> new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", java.util.Locale.UK).format(f.uploadDate)
      )),
      Enumerator.fromStream(f.inputStream)
    )

    case None => NotFound
  }
}
```

However, this often isn't the most performant option for serving files.  File systems are designed to do that or putting the url root behind a cache - eg varnish or deploying to cdn is often a better choice.